# The recording of Lecture Courses by Alexandre GROTHENDIECK in 1973

Tags: online-resources

According to the website
https://v1.archmathsci.org/catalogue/general-chronology-of-recordings-since-1973/chronology-of-recordings-1973-1980/1973-recordings/
There are Lecture Courses by Alexandre GROTHENDIECK three Lecture Courses on respectively

1. Algebraic Geometry
2. The Theory of Algebraic Groups
3. Topos Theory
   The copyright of all these recordings is that of the Department of Mathematics of SUNY at Buffalo to whose representatives

But I can't find them, is there anyone have found them? Thank you.

Comment: You might be interested in [Colin McLarty's lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vmcbm5FxRJE) on this topic in 2018.

Comment: http://www.neverendingbooks.org/grothendieck-talks

Comment: Thanks for the information!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find them here

https://agrothendieck.github.io/

in the section **audio**.